# SQL statement to JPQL

Tags: sql, jpql

I have used easier JPQL statements but trying to convert this statement into JPQL I fail:

```
SELECT * FROM DESADM.LROP_LOG_OPERAC WHERE DATE(O9384_TIMESLOG) = '2015-07-15'
```

The O9384_TIMESLOG column is Timestamp type, and I want to filter using the date, but not hour, etc

Thanks

Comment: What the entity code for the table DESADM? What JPQL query did you already try to do?